# Solr search with hyphen and camel case not returning expected results

Tags: solr, edismax

I have a solr search application which is failing in a specific case where the field value is both camelcased and hyphenated. Individually these cases work fine although together there is no match despite the field analysis page within solr matching the terms.

For example:

The field *myField* contains the value *camelCase-hyphen*. With the query value of *camelcase-hyphen* (note this is not camel cased) there is no match despite my WordDelimiterFilterFactory settings concatenating the entire term and then a LowerCaseFilterFactory follows.

The analysis page is showing a match but performing an actual search does not yield any results. See below.

My field type analysis is

```
<fieldtype name="textBlock" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"
                        ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                        words="stopwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                        generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                        catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory"
                        protected="protwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"
                        ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                        words="stopwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                        generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                        catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory"
                        protected="protwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

I am using Solr 3.6.1 and edismax.

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

[Verbose field analysis output](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16277757/solr/field%20analysis.html)

[Debug response](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16277757/solr/debug-response.xml)

Comment: Did you try using the Debugging feature & perhaps explainOther [Solr Debugging](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Debugging) Ex: ../?q=camelCase-hyphen&debugQuery=on

Comment: I've added links which show the full debug output.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your debug response posted here [Debug Response](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16277757/solr/debug-response.xml) , i can see your searching is matching at-least one document, so it is working as you would expect.

```xml
    <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
      <doc>
        <str name="a_searchable_name_t">camelcase-hyphen</str>
      </doc>
    </result>
```

Look at `numFound=1` it is having a match, but I guess you are still thinking you are not getting any result.Sorry I wanted to post this as a followup comment but the formatting & character limitations doesn't allow to elaborate.

Comment: There are 2 documents in the index one with the name "camelcase-hyphen" (which was found) and the other which was not found has a value of "camelCase-hyphen". The second document is one I am interested in.